# Execute action on link-to

Tags: ember.js

I want to add an action to a `{{link-to}}` helper.
For example, in a modal component, I use `{{link-to}}` to open a new route. When the user clicks the link, I want to close the modal through an action.

One possible solution is to wrap an action around a `{{link-to}}`:

```
<button {{action "close"}}>
  {{#link-to 'register'}}Registreer{{/link-to}}
</button>
```

Is this the best / cleanest solution possible? Or can I add an action to a link-to helper?

Another approach might be to transition and close in a custom action, but this approach is not 
usable for use in a component:

```
// template.hbs

<button {{action "link" "register"}}>Registreer</button>

...

// template-controller.js
actions: {
  link: function(routeName) {
    this.transitionToRoute(routeName);
    this.close()
  }
}
```

Comment: In my personal opinion, a component in the true sense of the word has no business doing routing-related things. It should communicate with the outside world (its invoking context) with terse actions, which it is then up to the caller to translate into something meaningful in the broader application context, whether that be a route transition or anything else.

Comment: Does you opinion change if the link-to logic is inside the yield part of the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do teardown operations such as closing modal boxes within the `willDestroyElement` event of your current `view`.

By doing this, you could just `{{link-to 'register'}}` and let your `view` (template-view.js) manage the fact that there is a modal to close or not.

Checkout the docs of willDestroyElement [HERE](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_willDestroyElement)